# Select all table rows from start to one in particular

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something with a calendar which is enclosed in a table. Basically, every day is a table cell. The today cell has a special class called... `.today` (quite original).

I want that, when the user clicks a day-cell it happens something. For the sake of usability I want to add a class to those days so the mouse cursor changes to a link-style.

I've been trying to do my best but, so far no luck.

So, for example, here are the first three weeks of May with today with the class named:

```
<table class="calendar">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="week0">
            <td class="day">30</td>
            <td class="day">1</td>
            <td class="day">2</td>
            <td class="day">3</td>
            <td class="day">4</td>
            <td class="day">5</td>
            <td class="day">6</td>                                                                  
        </tr>
        <tr class="week1">
            <td class="day">7</td>
            <td class="day">8</td>
            <td class="day">9</td>
            <td class="day">10</td>
            <td class="day">11</td>
            <td class="day">12</td>
            <td class="day">13</td>                                                                 
        </tr>
        <tr class="week2">
            <td class="day">14</td>
            <td class="day">15</td>
            <td class="day">16</td>
            <td class="day">17</td>
            <td class="day">18</td>
            <td class="day today">19</td>
            <td class="day">20</td>                                                                 
        </tr>               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select the tds from 30 (day) to 19.

Approaches taken:

- Select all days and then try to find the index of the today-cell. Fails, because a jQuery selection is not an array but an object.
- Use `$.each` and use a flag once `today` is reached. This works, but sounds really bad for performance [?]

Is there a way I'm missing?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Can you please try to share a few more details, and maybe an example.

Comment: Sure @JonathanSampson, example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of `.today` among all `td` elements and select based on that:

```
// Get the index of td.today among all td's
var tIndex = $(".today").index("td") + 1;

// Select all td's below (and including) .today
$("td:lt(" + tIndex + ")").css("background-color", "red");​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UNXve/

Comment: As I thought I was missing something because it was easy. Didn't know about that function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna My pleasure. I learn things every day on StackOverflow - glad to see you are doing the same ;)